# Why even after setting the classpath ,javax.servlet does not exist?

Tags: java, servlets

Even after setting the classpath i am not able to resolve this problem?
I am using tomcat and I set classpath=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;

Comment: It would help if you would provide details on what exactly your setup is and where are you facing the problem, IDE or server, and what classpath did you change and how?

Comment: Running with [`-varbose:class`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtm) might shed some light on your problem

Comment: Solved it . I was setting the classpath via a batch file , i dont know why but  it didn't worked . I typed the classpath in the command line and it worked perfectly.